# Prevent new line when outputting to console

Tags: c#, console, newline, buffer

I've set the buffer size to the window size to get rid of the scroll bar. Now, I'm trying to fill the console with a value, but there is always a new blank line added to the end, which causes the first line to be cleared from the buffer.

I know why it's happening, but is there any way that I can prevent it?

I've tried moving the buffer area, but as I said, the first line of the buffer is cleared when the blank line is added, so that just creates a blank line at the top.

Comment: If this is a programming question, then please post some code.

Comment: It has been some time since I touched C#, but isn't this a Console.write vs Console.writeln scenario?

Comment: Since when was actual code required for questions to be programming-related? It's obvious why this is happening. The console is automatically creating a new line when the length of the current line exceeds the window width. I just need to know how to get rid of the final empty line that this creates. Also, to answer Itay Moav's question, this is a Console.Write scenario.

Comment: The Console supports more than reading and writing - this is definitely a programming question, since it's about understanding an API.

Comment: Code isn't necessary in order to ask a question. It's just necessary in order for me to understand your question. I don't have any idea what you mean by "moving the buffer area", for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET console just streams into the buffer, which is probably not what you want.  You'll need to P/Invoke into the Windows API to have full control over the console.

In particular, check out [WriteConsoleOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687404(VS.85).aspx).  It allows you to treat the console as a grid of "pixels", and write to a specific block of them.